# create a function with different id selector

Tags: jquery

How to create a function that can accept different id's

I'm trying to create a function code to lessen the code redundancy

code:

```
            function getTableData(_tableName)
            {
                var array = [];
                var headers = [];
                var tableName = _tableName;
                var jsonData = '';
                $('#'+tableName+ 'th:not(:last-child)').each(function()
                {
                    headers.push($(this).attr('data-name'));
                })
                
                $('#'+tableName+ 'tbody tr').each(function() 
                {
                    var arrayItem = {};
                    $(this).find('td:not(:last-child)').each(function(i) 
                    {
                      arrayItem[headers[i]] = $(this).text();
                    })
                    array.push(arrayItem);
                });
                
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(array)
                return jsonData;
            }

            $('#btn-save-firstTable').on('click', function()
            {  
                var valueFd = getTableData('firstTable') //already tried $('#firstTable')  
                $.ajax(
                {
                        url: 'ajax/submit-application.php',
                        method:"POST",
                        dataType: "text",
                        data: { firstTable:  valueFd },
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                           alert(data);
                        }
                });
            });

            $('#btn-save-secondTable').on('click', function()
            {  
                var valueSd = getTableData('secondTable') //already tried $('#secondTable')  
                $.ajax(
                {
                        url: 'ajax/submit-application.php',
                        method:"POST",
                        dataType: "text",
                        data: { secondTable:  valueSd },
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                           alert(data);
                        }
                });
            });
```

how to generalize the function? or make it dynamically for any table ids..
or any suggestion for what i'm pointing of?

Comment: `#firstTableth:not(:last-child)` is most likely not how the selector should look like

Comment: Do you want to create a function which would accept different table ids and make the ajax call?

Comment: @praveenkaushik yes thats what i need.

Comment: @JoeLapogi Ok. Checkout my answer I just posted. Hope that answers the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out-
For reducing code redundancy, You can create a function which would take two parameters- tableSaveBtn and tableID

The code for the function will look like this-

```
function getdata(tableSaveBtn,tableID) 
{

        $(tableSaveBtn).on('click', function()
        {  
            var valueFd = getTableData(tableID)  
            $.ajax(
            {
                    url: 'ajax/submit-application.php',
                    method:"POST",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: { tableID:  valueFd },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                       alert(data);
                    }
            });
        });
}
```

You can call this getData() function from getTableData() function for as much Table IDs you want like this-

```
getData('#btn-save-firstTable','firstTable');
getData('#btn-save-secondTable','secondTable');
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: not working, i need my function to accept all id's, get all value/data inside table

Comment: Was the code that you posted earlier working? You have asked for code redundancy in your question, so I answered keeping that in mind only.